# How to load silverlight Entities with a large number of records?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, silverlight

I have a big table in my SQL Server database with 38000 records! When loading this table in my Silverlight application, it shows 0 records loaded. When I load the same table with less records (1000 for example ) the entity is loaded with all records!

Can anyone help me please?

```
      loadhabitaion = this.friendsContext.Load(this.friendsContext.GetHyd_poliQuery());
      loadhabitaion.Completed += new EventHandler(loadhabitaion_Completed);
      void loadhabitaion_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)

         {

        MessageBox.Show(loadhabitaion.Entities.Count().ToString());
          //it returns 0
         }
```

Comment: You need to show the code that loads the records. An event handler says nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the maximum amount of serialization.
Check the Web.config file for this section

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1310720"/>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx

Comment: Thx for your help !  ihad already tried this  <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>   but it doesn't resolve anything  .

Comment: @MehdiKylar Just curious but why do you want to load everything at once? Silverlight with Ria supports a relatively easy way of paging.

Comment: ; i am trying to add a deographique data  into my layer ,  so i have to load it at once !

Comment: @MehdiKylar Check out the second answer at: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/202753.aspx/1

Comment: i am using Ria services and not wcf services !  so i have i litlle problems when using that  code !  since  the domaineservice is generated automatically i dont now if i use (<service name="YOURPROJECT.Web.YOURSERVICE" in web.config)(didint work) or something else ?

Comment: @MehdiKylar Sorry. Perhaps you can see more information in the DomainService and your ouput window doing this in your DomainService class: `public override System.Collections.IEnumerable Query(QueryDescription queryDescription, out IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> validationErrors, out int totalCount)
{
  DataContext.Log = new DebuggerWriter();
  var result = base.Query(queryDescription, out validationErrors, out totalCount);
  return result;
}` for `DebuggerWriter` look here: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid0A1086040608245C7586A5EB7CB1CB5E8C346F39.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Change the configuration file and set the `<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>` as shown below.

This solved my issue and it will also solve yours.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <!--Added the next line so silverlight could recieve large data chunks-->
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```